# IE10 has extra margin above an inline header. How do I remove it?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-10

I have a `<h1>` within a `<header>`, and the header has `display: inline`. For some reason, in IE9 and IE10 only, there is an extra space above the `<h1>`. I've tried all the css resetting tricks I know, but nothing seems to remove this space.

How can I remove this extra space in IE9/10 without changing the html structure or tags, and without changing `display: inline` from the `<header>`? And without breaking it in other browsers?

HTML:

```
<header>
    <h1>
        why is there a space above this h1 in IE?
    </h1>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    /* padding/margin resets */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* and just so we can see each element */
    outline: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
header {
    display: inline;
}
```

[Here's a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/J4Vtc/23/)

Comment: BTW it is probably better to use the outline property to show the elements rather than an inset shadow. Like shadow, it does not take up space in the document, so it will not reposition elements, but you can style it more like a border, so it will show up better.

Comment: Thanks, @David Storey. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display `inline` and `inline-block` look at spaces in HTML. There's a line break before `<header>`, and between `<header>` and `<h1>`, which is what you're seeing. Since H1 itself is display: block;, I don't see the reason to use display: inline on the h1.

You could remove it using this:

```
body {
  font-size: 0; /* terrible idea */
}
header {
  font-size: 0;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 32px; /* can't be em, since parent is 0 */
}
```

Font-size at 0 effectively removes all the phantom text around your h1.

Comment: Olex, I've tried this, and it made no difference. Can you give a link to a working example?

Comment: Many browsers have a minimum font-size. This is usually something like 9px;

Comment: The fact that it's inline also means text _around_ the <header> gets interpreted. I updated to include font-size: 0; on the body - though that's a bad idea. [Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhjvw/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
h1 {margin-top: -5px;}
```

This will remove the space. It's a little hacky in the sense that you should be able to remove the space via some sort of reset but it does the job.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4Vtc/18/).

Comment: This breaks in other browsers.

Comment: What browsers? Everything I've tested so far is fine.

Comment: I tried it in Chrome, and the `h1` is 5px too short. I tried it in IE10, and the problem was not fixed.

Comment: Weird. Chrome is fine for me. FF too. Negative margins are a pretty standard way of positioning. I'll need to boot my partition to test IE 10.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, add:

```
h1 {
     position: absolute;
}
```

Adding this to the h1 tag should not change your layout too much because it is inside of the larger header.

Comment: In the page I need this to be fixed in, there is additional content after the header. This breaks that flow. I'd rather avoid `position: absolute`, as it removes the element fro the flow of the page.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have a block level element inside an inline element. It looks like IE is behaving differently in this case.

To fix it, use inline-block instead of inline: http://jsfiddle.net/J4Vtc/21/

```
header {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This still has a space for me in chrome.

Comment: I specifically asked that `display:inline` not be removed.

Comment: Why do you need it to be display: inline? That is quite odd. If you need it to be inline, inline-block will do much of what you need. Making the h1 inline too also fixes it, but the layout of the border box of the h1 is different, if that matters to you.

Comment: I'm using `header` to contain elements that describe what is coming up next. I'm using `display: inline` because any other display will break floating elements contained within the `header`. I'm /not/ using `display: block` because I need the content after the `header` to flow into the gap at the bottom of the `header` caused by the floated elements.